# is this use of objects redundant and/or inefficient?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

I'm fairly inexperienced with using objects so I would really like some input.

I'm trying to remove comments from a list that have certain "unwanted words" in them, both the comments and the list of "unwanted words" are in ArrayList objects.

This is inside of a class called `FormHelper`, which contains the private member `comments` as an ArrayList, the `auditList` ArrayList is created locally in a member function called `populateComments()`, which then calls this function (below). `PopulateComments()` is called by the constructor, and so this function only gets called once, when an instance of `FormHelper` is created.

```java
private void filterComments(ArrayList <String> auditList) {
    for(String badWord : auditList) {
        for (String thisComment : this.comments) {
            if(thisComment.contains(badWord)) {
                int index = this.comments.indexOf(thisComment);
                this.comments.remove(index);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

something about the way I implemented this doesn't feel right, I'm also concerned that I'm using ArrayList functions inefficiently. Is my suspicion correct?

Comment: Use `HashSet` instead.

Comment: your code will have `ConcurrentModificationException`. you need to use an iterator to remove comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not particularly efficient.  However, finding a more efficient solution is not straightforward.

Lets step back to a simpler problem.

```
private void findBadWords(List <String> wordList, List <String> auditList) {
    for(String badWord : auditList) {
        for (String word : wordList) {
            if (word.equals(badWord)) {
                System.err.println("Found a bad word");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose that `wordList` contains `N` words and `auditList` contains `M` words.  Some simple analysis will show that the inner loop is executed `N x M` times.   The `N` factor is unavoidable, but the `M` factor is disturbing.  It means that the more "bad" words you have to check for the longer it takes to check.

There is a better way to do this:

```
private void findBadWords(List <String> wordList, HashSet<String> auditWords) {
    for (String word : wordList) {
        if (auditWords.contains(word))) {
            System.err.println("Found a bad word");
        }
    }
}
```

Why is that better?  It is better (faster) because `HashSet::contains` doesn't need to check all of the audit words one at a time.  In fact, in the optimal case it will check none of them (!) and the average case just one or two of them.  (I won't go into why, but if you want to understand read the Wikipedia page on hash tables.)

---

But your problem is more complicated.  You are using `String::contains` to test if each comment contains each bad word.  That is not a simple string equality test (as per my simplified version).

What to do?

Well one potential solution is to split the the comments into an array of words (e.g. using `String::split` and then user the `HashSet` lookup approach.   However:

- That changes the behavior of your code.  (In a good way actually: read up on the [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem)!)  You will now only match the audit words is they are actual words in the comment text.
- Splitting a string into words is not cheap.  If you use `String::split` it entails creating and using a `Pattern` object to find the word boundaries, creating substrings for each word and putting them into an array.  You can probably do better, but it is always going to be a non-trivial calculation.

So the real question will be whether the optimization is going to pay off.  That is ultimately going to depend on the value of `M`; i.e. the number of bad words you are looking for.  The larger `M` is, the more likely it will be to split the comments into words and use a `HashSet` to test the words.

<sup>Another possible solution doesn't involve splitting the comments.  You could take the list of audit words and assemble them into a single regex like this:  `\b(word-1|word-2|...|word-n)\b`.  Then use this regex with `Matcher::find` to search each comment string for bad words.  The performance will depend on the optimizing capability of the regex engine in your Java platform.  It has the potential to be faster than splitting.</sup>

---

My advice would be to benchmark and profile your entire application *before you start*.  Only optimize:

1. when the benchmarking says that the *overall* performance of the requests where this comment checking occurs is concerning.  (If it is OK, don't waste your time optimizing.)
2. when the profiling says that *this* method is a performance hotspot.  (There is a good chance that the real hotspots are somewhere else.  If so, you should optimize *them* rather than this method.)

Note there is an assumption that you have (sufficiently) completed your application and created a realistic benchmark for it *before* you think about optimizing.  (Premature optimization is a bad idea ... unless you really know what you are doing.)

Comment: @AndyTurner - I am aware of that.  See my reference to the Scunthorpe problem a couple of paragraphs earlier.

Comment: sigh. Too early to read, clearly. What a... Scunthorpe I am :)

Answer (score 1):

As a general approach, removing individual elements from an ArrayList in a loop is inefficient, because it requires shifting all of the "following" elements along one position in the array.

```
A B C D E
  ^        if you remove this
    ^---^ you have to shift these 3 along by one
   / / /
A C D E
```

If you remove lots of elements, this will have a substantial impact on the time complexity. It's better to identify the elements to remove, and then remove them all at once.

I suggest that a neater way to do this would be using `removeIf`, which (at least for collection implementations such as `ArrayList`) does this "all at once" removal:

```
this.comments.removeIf(
    c -> auditList.stream().anyMatch(c::contains));
```

This is concise, but probably quite slow because it has to keep checking the entire comment string to see if it contains each bad word.

A probably faster way would be to use regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    auditList.stream()
        .map(Pattern::quote)
        .collect(joining("|")));
this.comments.removeIf(
    c -> p.matcher(c).find());
```

This would be better because the compiled regex would search for all of the bad words in a single pass over each comment.

The other advantage of a regex-based approach is that you can check case insensitively, by supplying the appropriate flag when compiling the regex.

Comment: This throws `unsupportedOperationException` on `removeIf`

Comment: How about this

`this.comments = this.comments.stream().filter(c -> !p.matcher(c).find()).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @muasif80 I presume you are trying this with an implementation of `List` which doesn't support removal then. OP's list does support removal, I'd imagine, or the `remove` wouldn't have worked in the first place.

Comment: Yes you are right actually I used Arrays.asList that gives back un modifiable list. Thanks

Comment: "A probably faster way would be to use regex" I don't know if regex is ever faster... Especially when you are using streams. I would look into using Apache Lang/Text...

Comment: @trilogy fast*er* doesn't mean fast*est*.